# The dependency OpenIddict in project does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

I did everything that was told [[on OpenIddict getting started tutorial]](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core#getting-started):

- I ran dnvm upgrade
- I've added all given sources to Nuget.Config
- Added "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*" to project.json dependencies

This is what Visual Studio tells when I hover my mouse over underlined in red "OpenIddict" dependence in project.json:

> The dependency OpenIddict 1.0.0-alpha2-0161 in project [...] does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0

Cleaning project and restoring nuget packages doesn't help. **What should I do to make it work?**

EDIT:

project.json:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "[...]",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.0.0-rc1-211161024",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which DNX runtime you're using?

Comment: @Pinpoint: after typing "dnx" to CMD: "Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc2-16595"

Comment: Weird. Could you also share your project.json?

Comment: Sure. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't use OpenIddict in an ASP.NET 5/Core RC1 application: **you must use ASP.NET Core RC2**, as mentioned in the [getting started page](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core#getting-started).

If you want to migrate to RC2, you can take a look at the `Mvc.Server` sample: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/samples/Mvc.Server.

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "warningsAsErrors": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,

    "embed": {
      "include": [ "Certificate.pfx" ]
    },

    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "config.json",
        "web.config"
      ]
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub": "1.0.0-alpha4-final",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection": "1.0.0-alpha1-final",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "OpenIddict": { "target": "project" }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"
      }
    },

    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702" }
      },

      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "config.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "netstandardapp1.5" in "framework"? What is does and why it is placed there instead of dnxcore50?

Comment: It also says that "'netstandardapp1.5' is an usupported framework

Comment: `netstandardapp1.5` is the new target framework moniker that replaces `dnxcore50`. Can you share the full error you're seeing and your updated project.json?

Comment: this is full error. " 'netstandardapp1.5' is an usupported framework". I don't have my computer right now with me, but all I changed are all "rc1-final" parts of dependency version to "rc2-*" and replaced "dnxcore50" with those five netstandardapp lines you showed in this answer. I will later update question with new project.json if you want.

Comment: Yes, please. Have you tried to clone and run the MVC sample?

Comment: Finally I figured it out: I had a min sdk version specified in global.json. This specified used sdk to RC1 so now it's clear why it didn't work. BUT, there are some other problems. Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc requires dnxcore50 (I've just removed it). Many of AspNetIdentity functions seems to be overrided by OpenIddict functions. What is see right now is giant mess.

Comment: `Many of AspNetIdentity functions seems to be overrided by OpenIddict functions.` > heh? Also, don't forget it's still an alpha project...

Comment: As I see on GitHub, you are contributor of this dependency. Can you say when will OpenIddict support dnxcore50? I'm afraid it won't help me with my API, maybe I will come back and use it later. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: OpenIddict already supports `dnxcore50` (replaced by `netstandard1.3`/`netstandardapp1.5` in the recent ASP.NET versions).

Comment: Well, everything changes so quickly in Asp.net nowadays. I wish I didn't start my project on release candidate version.

Comment: As the main guy behind the aspnet-contrib initiative, I share your pain. Reacting to all these breaking changes in extremely painful.

Comment: Answer updated to use the final ASP.NET Core RC2 packages.